# Проверка входных данных при решении квадртатного уравнения

Tags: python-3.x

Есть вот такой код:

```
print("Hello, user! This programm would find the roots of quadratic equation Ax^2 + Bx + C = 0")
A = input()
B = input()
C = input()
if (A.isdigit()) and (B.isdigit()) and (C.isdigit()):
    D = int(int(B)*int(B) - 4*int(A)*int(C))
    import math
    if D > 0:
        x1 = float((-int(B) + math.sqrt(D))/(2*int(A)))
        x2 = float((-int(B) - math.sqrt(D))/(2*int(A)))
        print("Two roots: x1 = ", x1, ", x2 = ", x2)
    elif D == 0:
        x = float(-int(B)/(2*int(A)))
        print("One root: x = ", x)
    else:
        print("No roots.")
else:
    print("Wrong input format.")
```

В случае, когда мы считаем, что A B C - целые числа, данный код проверяет входные A B C на корректность. **А каким образом можно выполнить проверку корректности входных данных (допустим, что бы пользователь не вводил текст) для вещественных ABC?**

Answer (score 1):

Добавил вот такую конструкцию при вводе:

```
try:
    A = float(input())
    B = float(input())
    C = float(input())
except ValueError:
    print("Wrong input format, try again. \n")
```

Проверяя эмпирическим путем, могу сказать, что этот вариант похож на правду. Но не уверен, что учтены все возможные ситуации.

Answer (score 0):

Можно воспользоваться [регулярными выражениями](https://tproger.ru/translations/regular-expression-python/). `(^\d+\.\d+$)|(^\d+$)` шаблон находит все строки, которые содержат любое количество чисел или которые содержат число, точку и число.

```
import re

pattern = r'(^\d+\.\d+$)|(^\d+$)' #задает шаблон поимка
pattern = re.compile(pattern)

a = input()
if pattern.match(a): 
    a = float(a)
else:
   print('Введено не допустимое значение')
```

Answer (score 0):

@FrostahG, ИМХО так полнее будет:

```
while True:
    try:
        A = float(input('Input "A": '))
        B = float(input('Input "B": '))
        C = float(input('Input "C": '))
    except ValueError:
        print("Wrong input format, try again. \n")
    else:
        break
```